# How to join a count query with another table which has all counts?

Tags: oracle, join, count

I am selecting count of few tables and i have a table named table_counts which has two columns named table_name and table_count. I want to join the result of the query with the table_name column of table_counts table. Please see the example below.

```
select 'Table 1' as table_name, count(*) as table_count_from table_1
union
select 'Table 2' as table_name, count(*) as table_count_from table_2
union
select 'Table 3' as table_name, count(*) as table_count_from table_3

------------------
++table_counts++++
------------------
table_name table count
Table 1     10
Table 2     20
Table 3     30
```

I have to join the two things using the table_name. Could someone help me if iam missing few things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are searching something like this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_counts  cnt
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select 'Table 1' as table_name, count(*) as table_count_from table_1
                    union
                   select 'Table 2' as table_name, count(*) as table_count_from table_2
                    union
                   select 'Table 3' as table_name, count(*) as table_count_from table_3
                  )  subcnt
    ON cnt.table_name = subcnt.table_name
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is what i needed.